# How to destructure and copy an array simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, spread-syntax

I know you can copy an array with the spread operator:

`const itemsArr = [...this.state.itemsArr];`

and you can destructure an array that's an object key's value:

`const { itemsArr } = this.state`

Is there a way to combine them into one step? Pseudocode:

`const { itemsArr } = [...this.state]`

or

`const { [...itemsArr] } = this.state`

**EDIT:** Is there a way to combine them into one step, ***so as to avoid typing "itemsArr" twice?***

Comment: You mean something like `const {itemsArr: [...itemsArr]} = this.state;`? You could also rename the variable: `const {itemsArr: [...renamedArray]} = this.state;`.

Comment: @Xufox hadn't thought of that way - essentially the same as `const itemsArr = [...this.state.itemsArr]` correct? Goal is to avoid typing "itemsArr" twice - I'll add that note to my question. Thanks!

Comment: No, you cannot without retyping

Comment: Currently, `const {[...itemsArr]} = this.state` is a SyntaxError, though I don’t have the knowledge of the spec to explain why… Maybe, this could become valid syntax in the future.

Comment: Why must you try to shorten you code so much with quirky syntax by combining destructuring? Just make the code readable.

Comment: @Xufox there's a proposal for an extension on destructuring object initializer to allow computed properties like `const { [o] } = …` but I don't think that extends to spread syntax.

Comment: It seems that spread works with arrays and destructure with literal objects, so you have to convert some into another.

Comment: @Li357 I didn't write the spec, just asking if this functionality exists in it. The first time I was introduced to destructuring I thought it was unreadable - now I use it just about every day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done by destructuring `itemsArr` from a copy of `state`:

```
const { itemsArr } = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state))
```

The strong point of this is that your nested objects are cloned, so your `state.itemsArr` is copied too and modifying `itemsArr` won't change the array in `state`.
The disadvantage is that if your `state` object contains functions, they won't be accessible using this method plus you can question the performance.

Another way to copy `state` is by using `Object.assign`:

```
const { itemsArr } = Object.assign({}, this.state)
```

With this you can access your functions inside of `state` but it makes a shallow copy, so `state.itemsArr` won't be cloned.

ECMAScript2018 actually has a spread operator that works with JSON objects:

```
const { itemsArr } = { ...this.state }
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/32qvzjy2op (look at your browser's console, the one in the tool is bad).

But then again, it only makes a shallow copy.

The best way would be to write/import a `deepCopy` function that clones the object with it's nested properties and functions.

https://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep

Comment: The ECMAScript2018 snippet is closest to what I was looking for, thanks. +1 for `Object.assign`, didn't think of that